# silverlight from 4 to 5 upgrade ria services compilation error

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I've upgraded silverlight project from 4 to 5 and now have compilation error where I load data to the DomainContext:

```
Context.Load(Context.GetMyEntityQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, null, null);


The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 

'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load<MyEntity>(System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery<MyEntity>, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadBehavior, System.Action<System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation<MyEntity>>, object)
'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load          (System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery,           System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadBehavior, System.Action<System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation>,           object)'
```

Any ideas how to fix this (and I have > 100 such errors)?

**Edit**

Calling like this helps:

```
Context.Load<MyEntity>(Context.GetMyEntityQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, null, null);
```

The culprit is this overload (assembly System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll, v2.0.5.0)

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public virtual LoadOperation Load(EntityQuery query, LoadBehavior loadBehavior, Action<LoadOperation> callback, object userState);
```

together with this

```
public LoadOperation<TEntity> Load<TEntity>(EntityQuery<TEntity> query, LoadBehavior loadBehavior, Action<LoadOperation<TEntity>> callback, object userState) where TEntity : Entity;
```

It seems the later is enough so why the former is included? Anyway, will investigate further (it seems I reference the latest ria services 1.0 SP2, cleaning everything and rebuilding not helping).

Comment: Check your references. Ria Services dll's especially in your silverlight project. delete generated code and rebuild. We did it without headache.

Comment: Try to express <MyEntity> as requested by the compiler? Checkout, clean and rebuild all your references to the domainservice.

Answer (score 0):

I used to load data to **DomainContext** in the following way.

```
public void GetPersonObjectDataFromService(Action<LoadOperation<TempPersonDTO>>    loadData)
    {                                           
          var query1 = this.tpDataProviderContext1.GetPersonObjectDataFromServiceQuery();
          tpDataProviderContext1.Load(query1, LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, loadData, null);
    }
```

TempPersonDTO is Class which having data.
Thank you.